# Заполнение одномерного массива C++

Tags: c++

Одномерный массив m[15] должен заполниться случайными числами. Попробовал так

```
for(i = 0; i < 15; i++) { m[i] = rand() % 100; }
```

Программа работает, числа задаются, но почему-то всегда одни и те же, т.е. всегда создаёт один и тот же массив с одними и теми же числами. Как сделать, чтоб каждый раз числа были разные.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В начале программы вызови

```
#include <ctime>

srand(time(NULL));
```